# Getting maximum value from multiple values output (list of numbers) using Calculate Value in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, multi-values

I have an output from a sub model that iterates through feature classes, each with a row count. The row counts are passed to a collect values, which is a model parameter and is used outside the sub model.

How can i use simple code in a "calculate value" tool to get the maximum value from this list of numbers. I wish to then use this as a precondition to subsequent analysis so that if the sub model does not produce results then the subsequent analysis will not run.

This is similar to [Exporting data from Collect Values output in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25998) that wished to use the actual list of numbers. The answer suggested an export to .csv file.

I only need to use a simple output so that I can use it as a pre condition on subsequent analysis. I have tried to calculate the Max(list), but it has not worked.

Comment: You might find [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4916/calculate-value-using-maximum-value-from-different-feature-class) helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I checked again, unfortunately the "summary statistics" and the  "Get Field Value" cannot be linked to the output of "collect values" from an iterator, which is why i was trying to find a way by using the "calculate value" tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK you have a model that is collecting values (of type long) and its a parameter. This is a sub model to the master model. In the master model connect your collection of values as a precondition to a Calculate Value tool. These collected values are called "Output Values".

In your Calculate Values tool:

**Expression:**

```
summe("%Output Values%")
```

**Code Block:**

```
import string
def summe(s):
  l = string.split(s,";")
  max = -1
  for i in l:
    if i > max:
      max = i
  return max
```

**Data type:**

Long

This approach is taking advantage of the fact that your collected values are "MultiValues" which are semicolon separated.

[image: Example model finding the max value in a multivalue list]

Comment: i have just check this and it works brilliantly. thanks very much. Jonathan

Comment: So from '8;22', is '8' is the largest string, but 22 is the largest number.

Comment: This can be done in one expression `max([int(x) for x in !Output_Values!.split(';')])` (no code block)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've got a three step process: 
a) Values from each iteration
b) Max value from all iterations
c) use the max value to calculate additional steps for each iteration.

A workaround might be to use 'Append' to join the outputs of each of the iterations to a single file. Then you can use 'Max' on that file.

Alternately, use a 'merge' on the collected values, and then use summary statistics.